# Singular or plural form of the verb here?

Tags: accord, pluriel

In the following sentence : "Bref, ce mélange unique de similitudes et de divergences, ainsi que mon désir de renforcer ma maîtrise de la langue espagnole, **m'a** toujours motivé à découvrir votre pays."

Should I replace the *m'a* with *m'ont*, since I'm talking about two distinct elements?

Answer (score 2):

Original answer:

I think you should make the agreement. Since there are two elements mentioned (mélange and désir), you should use "m'ont" to agree with the plural subject. The correct sentence in my humble opinion would be:

> "Bref, ce mélange unique de similitudes et de divergences, ainsi que mon désir de renforcer ma maîtrise de la langue espagnole, **m'ont** toujours motivé à découvrir votre pays."

---

**New Edit (25/01/2024)** following the comments and [this content](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/24219/la-grammaire/le-verbe/accord-du-verbe-avec-le-sujet/sujets-joints-par-une-conjonction/accord-du-verbe-avec-des-sujets-neutres-coordonnes):

Note that there is a debate regarding the agreement here. Some argue for a singular agreement with 'ce mélange' as the main subject, while others advocate for a plural agreement due to the presence of two distinct elements. Both forms may be considered grammatically acceptable, and the choice may depend on the interpretation of the relationship between the main subject and the ainsi que clause.
More specificaly,

- Singular Agreement (m'a): The argument here is that the singular
  agreement may be justified because the main subject is "ce mélange"
  (this mixture), which is singular. The ainsi que clause might be seen
  as a parallel construction rather than combining with the main
  subject to form a plural subject.
- Plural Agreement (m'ont): The argument in favor of the plural
  agreement suggests that since there are two distinct elements
  mentioned (mélange and désir), it makes sense to use the plural form
  to agree with the combined subjects.

Hence,

> Bref, ce mélange unique de similitudes et de divergences, ainsi que mon désir de renforcer ma maîtrise de la langue espagnole, m'a/m'ont toujours motivé à découvrir votre pays.

Comment: At first, I was about to agree with that, but now I'm thinking it's not so clear cut. You could make a case that the real subject is the singular _mélange_, and that the _ainsi_ clause is "parallel" to that subject rather than resulting in a plural subject.

Comment: @Frank should I correct/modify my answer?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm on the fence :-) I would naturally prefer the plural, but I can't convince myself the singular is really wrong. In the end, both seem possible.

Comment: @Frank thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: I would go with the singular myself. I parse the *ainsi* clause as a sort of comparison, similar to an English sentence like "His pride, just as much as his fear, holds him back."

Comment: @LukeSawczak thanks. Should I correct it or leaving my answer as it is, making reference to the comment section?

Comment: There is something to be said for Luke's point of view, but _ainsi que_ would maybe tilt the balance towards accumulating two things, which is less the case in _just as much_?

Comment: @LukeSawczak In English/American I would probably say "His pride, just as much as his fear, are holding him back." But I would not flinch if someone used as a singular construction.

Comment: @Brandin: I am fairly sure that in formal English, you are supposed to use the singular in sentences like these. See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56210/singular-or-plural-verb-form-where-subject-includes-a-parenthetical-element) on English stackexchange. But French is a different language, with different rules. I don't think English sheds any light on it for this case.

Comment: @PeterShor It doesn't seem there's really a consensus for this issue in English either. Sure, French and English are different languages, but at least for this point of grammar it seems like both language communities are thinking about the same thing. I could think either of them is valid. "His pride as much as his fear, (either one of those) holds him back" or as "His pride as much as his fear, (both of those) hold him back". Where the word in parens is the idea that you've got in your head when you're constructing the singular/plural concept in your brain.

Comment: @Brandin: I'm pretty sure that the consensus of English grammarians is that you should use a singular verb there. See [this web page](https://www.grammar.com/subject-verb-agreement-plural-subjects/), which says *'Beware of words that join but do not qualify as true conjunctions and thus do not form plural subjects. These words include as well as, along with, together with, not to mention, and others."* On the other hand, what English speakers actually do doesn't always comply with this rule.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular sentence, I believe the verb can only be in the plural. According to my favorite Grevisse (*Le français correct*, 1984):

> (985) Subjects linked by AINSI QUE, COMME, AVEC, etc.
>
> a) If the conjunction is copulative ( = aggregates subject elements),
> the verb agrees with the whole:   Le français ainsi que l'italien
> DÉRIVENT du latin (Littré). - Aussi bien l'oncle Mathieu que tante
> Philomène n'ÉTAIENT pour moi que sons (H. Bosco). - La voix non plus
> que la silhouette ne lui ÉTAIENT connues (A. de Châteaubriant). - Le
> murmure des sources avec le hennissement des licornes se MÊLENT à
> leurs voix (Flaubert). - L'une comme l'autre GARDENT peu de loisir
> disponible pour l'aventure (M. Prévost). - Tant le sol boueux que
> l'eau m'ÉTAIENT présents (H. Bosco).
>
> b) If the conjunction clearly puts the elements in comparision, the
> agreement is with the first element:
> Le français, ainsi que l'italien, DÉRIVE
> du latin (Littré). - Son visage, aussi bien que son cœur, AVAIT
> rajeuni de dix ans (Musset). - Le manque d'air ici, autant que
> l'ennui, FAIT bâiller (A. Gide). - L'un comme l'autre EST pris au jeu
> (Id.). - La religion, comme la politique, A ses Brutus (A. Hermant). -
> Renée, pas plus que Gilbert, n'ÉTAIT retournée chez les Guillaume (M.
> Arland).
>
> Same (with AVEC), if one element is clearly accessory to the other:
> Le travail
> avec ses servitudes lui INSPIRA de bonne heure un grand dégoût (M.
> Garçon).

In the present case, the mix of similitudes & divergences neither approaches nor opposes the desire to master the language; they are just two juxtaposed, separate incentives. The conjunction is copulative in meaning, not comparative, whence:

... **m'ont** toujours motivé.

(Edited after jlliagre's comments)

**Disclaimer.** My approach is *descriptive* not *prescriptive*, maybe I should add this to my SE profile. I am not a party in any effort at normalizing French, only explaining how I write it.
In particular, I write w/o regard to the ongoing normalization process. I *guess* it systematically moves towards relaxing the rules I follow, not toward invalidating them; I have not checked though. **End of disclaimer.**

Back to the question at hand: on the prescriptive side and as far as I know (which need not include the latest news, see above), school teachers are now instructed to accept both singular and plural in every instance, as reflecting the 2 equally valid intents of the writer.

Finally, I will add a word about commas. Grevisse's examples clearly show they are optional and somehow related to the chosen agreement: his editors, if noone else, prefer them with the singular. However, he has not a word about them in the entire section I quoted, so I believe the subject is quite distinct.
My own opinion is, punctuation comes *after* deciding the contents of the text and the comma basically marks where *speakers* pause; if they help silent *readers* (which they certainly do, so typesetters and editors will inevitably have their say about this), it is secondary.

Comment: Curieux, j'aurais conclu exactement le contraire à partir des mêmes éléments.

Comment: Sur quelle échelle un mélange unique se compare-t-il à un désir de renforcer? En quelle unité peut-elle être graduée? Aucune, à mon avis.

Comment: L'absence de virgule, deux sujets coordonnés, impose le pluriel, on est d'accord la dessus. La présence d'une virgule détache l'élément mis en apposition qui n'est donc pas un élément essentiel de la phrase. Dans ce cas, l'accord est libre. J'aurais quand même mis le pluriel mais je ne considère pas le singulier comme une erreur.

Comment: Ces considérations nous éloignent de Grevisse. Pour y revenir: sa règle n'est pas que dans toute phrase, un seul des les deux accords, singulier ou pluriel, est grammatical; c'est que pour admettre le singulier, "ainsi que" DOIT dénoter UNE COMPARAISON entre les deux éléments; doit les METTRE EN BALANCE d'au moins une manière.

Comment: L'exemple de Littré illustre parfaitement qu'une même phrase *peut* admettre l'un et l'autre accords.

Comment: Grevisse ne donne pas d'exemple d'accord au pluriel quand l'un des éléments est mis en apposition comme dans la phrase qui nous intéresse. Je dirais donc qu'il ne traite pas ce cas particulier.

Comment: En ce cas la situation n'a plus rien de curieux: de ces mêmes éléments menant à des conclusions exactement contraires, le principal n'intervient pas dans le raisonnement.